# Does applicationDidBecomeActive: block the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

In my app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, I check for validity of the user's login status, to throw up a login page if it fails. This check involves a network call, and my fear is that in poor network situations it may block the main UI, effectively making the app hang.

What happens from a timing perspective when the app becomes active? Do the contents of `applicationDidBecomeActive:` block/run on the main thread? Should I be doing this network call asynchronously (e.g. using GCD)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `applicationDidBecomeActive` method is called on the main thread like all UIKit methods. You must always make sure that you perform any long running processes or networking access in a background thread.

Use the asynchronous form of `NSURLConnection` or use GCD to perform the action on a background queue.

Answer (score 2):

You should not perform synchronous network operations in any of your application delegate `applicationDid...` methods (well, you shouldn't do synchronous network operations anywhere in your program). In fact, iOS will terminate your app if it takes a long time to respond to launch/background/resume events. The crash log will state that `<Your app> failed to launch in time`.